# Android - Benefit of using actionbar over a view?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

Recently I've heard the recommendation of using actionbar to manage user actions and navigation in the app.

However to implement this and have my app be compatible with lower versions I have to use actionbarsherlock, also I'll have to change some themes, so it comes to my mind: All this looks like a lot of effort when I could just add a custom view to my activities' layout as they need it.

Is there a real benefit in performance or something when using action bar?

Comment: kind of offtopic but Roman Nurik said at the google i/o this year that they are going to be releasing a compatibility actionbar soon to use instead of actionbarsherlock. You can see it in the google i/o app. So if this is not of huge importance you might want to hold out for a bit

Comment: I think that while the idea of having standard UI parts such as the ActionBar and its menus is great, in the real life I encounter too many limitations. Just an example - try to put the title in the center. True - you can use a custom layout, but then the setTitle() does not work (at least I couldn't find a simple way to make it work...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's more about user experience. The action bar makes an interface consistent across applications. Here is the quote from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

> "You should use the action bar in most activities that need to prominently present user actions or global navigation, because the action bar offers users a consistent interface across applications and the system gracefully adapts the action bar's appearance for different screen configurations".

The developer site also says [the primary goals of the action bar are to:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

- Provide a dedicated space for identifying the application brand and user location.
- Provide consistent navigation and view refinement across different applications.
- Make key actions for the activity (such as "search", "create", "share", etc.) prominent and accessible to the user in a predictable way.

Comment: Yes that may be the reason, I have been using ActionBar since I asked, and in my personal experience, it became cleaner to code screens, easier to implement tabs or navigation. The only "problem" I see is the lack of flexibility with the design, which may be the issue you address: "familiar user experience"